# UINavigationController Custom popViewControllerAnimated Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have made a custom UINavigationController class so that I can have a UIAlertView popup and say, are you sure you want to leave this view when tapping the back button.

I have a customer the method like so below:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] class] == [weddingSetupController class]){

        UIAlertView *exitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" 
                                  message:@"By leaving the setup, all current changes will be lost. The setup can be retsrated later if you decide to leave now. However, it is recomened for your best experience that you complete the setup." 
                                  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" 
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil
                                  ];

        [exitAlert show];

        return nil;
    } 
    else {
        return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }
}
```

It works well, although an issue is, that while if I say 'No', it stays on the same view, not popping the parent view, the navigation bar does pop. So I get the view not to pop but the bar always returns to the state of its parent view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press the back button on the navigation bar, it's calling:

```
- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

in UINavigationBar, which in turn calls popViewControllerAnimated on the navigation controller.  Override this method (I use a category, to avoid subclassing) and take your same approach.  Your overriding point was just a step late.

Comment: how do you get the viewcontroller that answers the question if a pop is allowed from within the NavigationBar?

Comment: Hey Jacob, could you explain or possibly show how did you use a category to override this method.  If you have a category defined like: @interface UINavigationController (BackBtnAdditionLogic), and override popViewControllerAnimated. All back button in application will be override.  I am trying to avoid that, only a few ViewControllers needs customized logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think that ideally, the user never has to "save" anything - everything is saved implicitly.  So if they leave setup and come back later, they should be able to resume where they left off.

But if you still want to do it this way, it might work better to use a modal view with Cancel and Done buttons at the top.  And now that I think of it, Mail will ask you to save a unsent draft using an action sheet.